# Flutter. How to animate reordered ListView?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, flutter-animatedlist, reorderable-list

Is it possible to animate the change of the order of a ListView like ReorderableListView, but without User interaction.

Means for example, after a few seconds of time the order of the ListView changes.
So I have two Lists with the same items but in another order.
ListOne and ListTwo.

I already saw AnimatedList, But there I can just do delete or add animation.
I need something like move animation.

Somehow like ReorderableListView, but without the user interaction.
Or is it maybe possible to replace the user interaction programmatically in ReorderableListView?

Thanks in advance