# is there any way to change order an item of ReorderableListView programmatically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, reorderable-list

is there any way to change order an item of ReorderableListView programmatically in flutter? i didnt find anything about it on web. all sources talk about user drag and drop event but i need change order programmatically.

i tried animatedlist but there is no method to update order an item, only remove or insert an item.then i tried with stack, list and slidetransition but I gave up because it was complicated so it could have bugs. then i tried with simulate tap and drag event, i couldnt do it.

any idea about it?

Comment: did you find this? im also looking

Comment: no bro, i cant any solution until flutter 3.0. i dont know new changes after 3.0

Comment: Looks like same question was asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828258/flutter-how-to-animate-reordered-listview and still no answer :/